# Wide margin in mobile view with too many !important tags

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm having a problem with the css on my website. It looks fine in desktop view, but in mobile view there is a large right margin that distorts the sidebar. Here's the link to the page. https://www.bearcountrybees.com/store/

If you have any input on what I should do to fix it that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: If you can input the HTML and CSS code here, it would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Emphasis on minimal.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are setting a value for the wrappers width with `important` where it should be 100% for mobile screens and try to avoid using `important` cause to override them we'll have to use more `important`'s.Like,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .bSe right,
 .sAsCont .sAs {
   width: 100%;
 }
}
```

If it is really necessary use `important` ie.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .bSe right,
 .sAsCont .sAs {
   width: 100% !important;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you haven't used any framework like BootStrap for your website. From next time, please use a framework, it will solve a lot of problems for you.

You could widen the sidebar to full width on mobile screens like this.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.sAs {
   width: 100% !important;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had too many width applied on the **.bSeCont .bSe** , the best way to do CSS is for you, the last one was the rules that cause your page to be having a large margin on the right is the .bSeCont .bSe { width: 67% !important; } on line 409. One way to fix that is for you to be very specific on your css to be able to override that... Try this one...

```
.cnt .bSeCont .bSe.right { width: 100%!important; }
```